# How to make working pycharm terminal script work in ide?

Tags: python, powershell, terminal

I have a script executing pytests:

py -m pytest

it works in pycharm terminal, but doesnt in .py script:
exec('''py -m pytest''')

also it doesnt work in powershell
what is a diference in pycharm Terminal and powershell

Should i add a directory somehow?
how to make it work?

Comment: Try starting PS by right click shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: What is `py` here ? is it `Python` ? then type `path` in the console to see if your python folder is in the list and try `python -m` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute other python scripts from a python script using `import`.
I assume pytest.py is in the same folder as the python you are running yourself, so the code would be: `import pytest`.

The `exec()` function in python executes a string of python code.
For example:

```
code = '''
print("Hello, world!")
name = input("What's your name?")
print(f"Nice to meet you {name}!")
'''

exec(code)
```

Therefore you could also use `exec()` to execute a python file:

```
with open("pytest.py", "r") as f:
    code = f.read()

exec(code)
```

And to answer your second question. The pycharm terminal automatically puts you in the correct folder, while in powershell you have to navigate to the correct folder and then you can use py -m pytest.

A little tip for the next time you ask a question. Try giving more information. Instead of just saying it doesn't work, maybe also give the error code it gave if any.

Comment: I cannot run an pytest script just by puting the string of it in exec(string) like you suggested, it returns nothing and i see on my testing server that test was not exexuted. There is no error code, just nothing happens

Comment: @T125p I don't know if this might fix the solution, but you can use `c = compile(code, "pytest", "exec")` and then you can replace `exec(code)` with `exec(c)`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tomek\Desktop\Praca\generator\helper.py", line 13, in <module>
    c = compile(r'''py -m pytest C:\Users\tomek\Desktop\Praca\generator\Test0.py''', "pytest", "exec")
  File "pytest", line 1
    py -m pytest C:\Users\tomek\Desktop\Praca\generator\Test0.py
          ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: inside the `compile()` you shouldn't use the path. The `code` variable should be gotten from `open(...)`.